# database connection (open/close) performance

Tags: database, performance, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've some doubts about database connections:

1. Should I open and close the database every time that I execute a query? (it's almost every time)
2. If I'm downloading some JSON files at the same time, on it's onload function, while I'm running the insert querys (some times at the same time), lets say that the 1st insert function is done, if I close the database and the 2nd function is still inserting the data, closing the 1st database connection will affect the 2nd one?

(note that these are 2 separated functions, but running at the same
    time, depending on the onload function and the size of JSON file
    data)

3. If I'm almost always using database connections, what's the best approach in order to avoid memory leaks and consume less memory?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Database_Best_Practices). As it says, in a mobile app, don't use connection pooling. You should close the connection every time after you're done dealing with it. You might execute multiple queries at once. In that case, of course you keep the connection open until all are executed.
2. No.
3. Use Alloy Models. Alloy handles best database practices for you.

Answer (score 1):

1) No - Use connection pools.
2) Each transaction must be atomic. Avoid sharing state to avoid losing hair and health.